# why does the parent pid return a different value than getpid()?

Tags: c, unix, fork, pid

According to the man page

> getpid()  returns  the  process  ID (PID) of the calling process.

1. In the following code why does the `parent pid` return a different value than `getpid()` ?
2. Isn't the main process the same as the parent process?
3. And why do I get different outputs when run on a different system?

---

```
#include <sys/types.h>                  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    printf("getpid = %d \n", (int)getpid());

    pid_t pid = fork();
    printf("fork returned %d \n", (int)pid);

    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        perror("fork failed");
        break;

    case 0:
        printf("I am a child  with pid = %d\n", (int)pid);
        break;

    default:
        printf("I am a parent with pid = %d\n", (int)pid);

        break;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

output when i run :

```
getpid = 8208 
fork returned 8209 
I am a parent with pid = 8209
fork returned 0 
I am a child  with pid = 0
```

output when run on a different pc:

```
getpid = 2522 
fork returned 2523 
I am a parent with pid = 2522
fork returned 0 
I am a child  with pid = 2523
```

Comment: You must call `getpid` _after_ the `fork` because `fork` creates a _new_ process with a _new_ pid.

Comment: Either your other PC is utterly broken, or you are not running what you think you are running.

Comment: Whink about the value of `pid` when you `switch` on it, land in `case 0` and wheter that can really be a pid.

Comment: Your other PC does not produce the output you claim from the code you claim to be running on it.  Recopy the code from the machine where you get correct output to the machine where you don't, recompile the program on the second machine, and run it (but don't lose the first program — make backup copies, etc).  It is very improbable that the recompiled code produces the answer you claim the unrecompiled code produces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the parent process and main process are the same thing.

This snippet of your code should give you a clue about the solution:

```
switch (pid) {
    /* ... */
    case 0:
        printf("I am a child  with pid = %d\n", (int)pid);
        break;
```

This effectively says "if `pid` is zero then the child pid is always zero". This obviously cannot be true, so it is your interpretation of `fork()`'s return value that is incorrect.

The man page states:

> Upon successful completion, fork() returns a value of 0 to the child process and returns the process ID of the child process to the parent process.

So the variable `pid` *in the parent process* is the pid of the *child*, **NOT** the parent's own pid.

*In the child process*, you would need to call `getpid()` after `fork()` to get the child's own pid.

Answer (score 1):

`fork` duplicates a process and after the fork, they both run in parallel. To tell the program whether it is a child or the parent, it returns 0 for the child and the PID of the child process is returned in the parent.

So after the fork, you must call `getpid()` for both parent and child, in your code that would be:

```
    pid_t thispid= getpid(); 
    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        perror("fork failed");
        break;

    case 0:
        printf("I am a child  with pid = %d\n", (int)thispid);
        break;

    default:
        printf("I am a parent with pid = %d\n", (int)thispid);
        break;

    }
```